# Cocoa preprocessor exit file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, c-preprocessor, exit

I've seen some compilers that lets you stop reading the file where ever in the file you want
and I want to know if obj-c has such thing here's an example, so you can understand:

```
#ifndef __OBJC__   // or #if !defined(__OBJC__)
#exit  // do not continue compiling this file!
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't simply stop compilation in the middle of the file. You'd have to structure it this way:

```
#if __OBJC__
// the rest of the file
#endif
```